# Where to make feature requests?

Tags: feature-request

The elementary OS StackExchange is not meant for feature requests or reports on [bugs](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/170).

I know where to report bugs. What about feature requests?

Comment: launchpad as well.

Comment: @Tim - please could you post a link to what page  - and that preferably as an answer here?

Comment: @Tim -feature requests are to be posted as bugs?

Comment: Yes - see Daniel's answer.

Comment: Really, this question should be on the main site, not meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as elementary is concerned, feature requests and bug reports are the same thing. They should both be reported in GitHub following the same guidelines.

Also, this is Meta. Questions here should be about the elementary OS Stack Exchange ;)

Comment: The question was about SE: "Is SE the right place to make feature requests?"...